# XCtest UI testing - running test stalls on wait for app to idle

Tags: xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I'm have just starting using **XCTest** for UI testing.
While running my tests, execution takes forever.

I get following output:

```
Wait for app to idle - waits 120 seconds to fail
    App animations complete notification not received, will attempt to continue.
```

I have looked all over and found zero answer on how to either change the timeout or how to manipulate the app to move on.

There are no animations running at all in the app.  The screen is fully loaded.  My developers also have zero answers as well and I have tried disabling animations which fails the tests outright.

Any ideas on how I can address this?

```
 func testHomeScreen() {
        logIn()

        let home = app.navigationBars["HOME"].staticTexts["HOME"]
        waitForElementToAppear(element: home)
        XCTAssert(home.exists)

        let myFriendsButton = app.buttons["My Friends"]
        XCTAssert(myFriendsButton.exists)

        let collectionViewsQuery = app.collectionViews
        collectionViewsQuery.buttons["compose"].tap()
        app.navigationBars["CREATE POST"].buttons["CANCEL"].tap()
        collectionViewsQuery.buttons["photo"].tap()
        app.navigationBars["PHOTO BOOTH"].buttons["CANCEL"].tap()

        let element = collectionViewsQuery.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 1).children(matching: .other).element
        element.children(matching: .other).element(boundBy: 0).children(matching: .image).element(boundBy: 0).tap()

        let profileCloseButton = app.buttons["profile close"]
        profileCloseButton.tap()

        let image = element.children(matching: .image).element
        image.swipeUp()

        let button = app.navigationBars["DETAILS"].buttons[" "]

        let cell = collectionViewsQuery.children(matching: .cell).element(boundBy: 0)
        cell.buttons["actionsheet"].tap()
        app.sheets.buttons["Cancel"].tap()
        cell.buttons["comment"].tap()
        button.tap()
        collectionViewsQuery.buttons["like selected"].tap()
```

Here is my LogIn func and Setup.

func logIn() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

```
if  app.tabBars.buttons["HOME"].exists {
    logOut()
}
let logInButton = app.buttons["LOG IN"]
logInButton.tap()

let elementsQuery = app.scrollViews.otherElements
let emailField = elementsQuery.textFields["example@email.com"]
emailField.tap()
emailField.typeText("***************")

let passwordSecureTextField = elementsQuery.secureTextFields["Password"]
passwordSecureTextField.tap()
passwordSecureTextField.typeText("************")

app.navigationBars["LOG IN"].buttons["btn login"].tap()

if app.staticTexts["PLEASE TURN ON NOTIFICATIONS"].exists {
    XCTAssert(app.staticTexts["This way you will be able to see when your friends post, message, like or comment on your stuff!"].exists)
    app.buttons["NOT NOW"].tap()

}

if app.collectionViews.staticTexts["3D Rooms Now Available!"].exists {
    XCTAssert(app.collectionViews.staticTexts["Chat with friends in 3D rooms wherever you go! Tap here to get started"].exists)
    app.collectionViews.buttons["close"].tap()
}


if app.staticTexts["DAILY"].exists {
    XCTAssert(app.staticTexts[" SPIN"].exists)
    app.buttons["close"].tap()
}
```

}

Setup:

class HomeScreenTests: XCTestCase {
    let app = XCUIApplication()

```
override func setUp() {
    super.setUp()

    // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.

    // In UI tests it is usually best to stop immediately when a failure occurs.
    continueAfterFailure = false
    // UI tests must launch the application that they test. Doing this in setup will make sure it happens for each test method.
    app.launch()


    // In UI tests it’s important to set the initial state - such as interface orientation - required for your tests before they run. The setUp method is a good place to do this.
}
```

Here is a chunk of the output from the test logs:

[LogFile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVLjI.png)

Comment: Can you please add the code of your UITest class?

Comment: I added the code.  It's largely generated via the recorder.

Comment: The code looks ok. Can you also post the `login()` method? Also, what are you doing in `setUp()`?

Comment: Added.  All of it is pretty basic and shouldn't impact much.  The only thing I can think of is that the app itself has some process running in the background that the test run is waiting for.  I just need to convince the developers to take it seriously and look at what it may be.  Unless I can find my own solution that is.

Comment: When you run the test, does the test runner press the Login Button or is nothing happening at all? Is the output that you've posted everything you get or is there more?

Comment: I added an image of the log file.  What happens is it will log in and then wait the 120 seconds to fail for app idle.  Then it will move on with the tests and at another point where nothing is happening on screen, it will wait again.  these points do not have any animations happening since the screen is fully loaded.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue, so I am afraid I cannot help you on this one.

Comment: I'm guessing it has more to do with how the app is coded and less to do with the execution of the tests.  Thanks anyway.